# How to make a shape move to click in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, shapes

I am trying to make to make a shape move to wherever I click my mouse. I got the shape to move, and it moves towards the general direction of where I clicked, but it never moves exactly to where I clicked, it misses by a good distance. Since it doesn't move exactly to where I clicked, the shape continues to move and doesn't stop.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GraphicsTester extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    private int startX;
    private int startY;
    private int endX;
    private int endY;
    private int stepX;
    private int stepY;
    private Timer sliderTimer = new Timer(40, new SlideListener());

    public GraphicsTester() throws IOException {
        setTitle("Graphics Tester 1");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel basePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                g2d.fillOval(215 + stepX, 215 + stepY, 30, 30);
                startX = stepX;
                startY = stepY;
                if (215 + stepX == endX && 215 + stepY == endY) {
                    sliderTimer.stop();
                }
            }
        };
        basePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        basePanel.addMouseListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(basePanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new GraphicsTester();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        endX = e.getX();
        endY = e.getY();
        System.out.println("endX: " + endX + ", endY: " + endY);
        sliderTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    private class SlideListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stepX += (endX - startX) / 5; // the 5's are just arbitrary values, I chose 5 because it makes the shape slide at the speed I want
            stepY += (endY - startY) / 5;
            System.out.println("stepX: " + (215 + stepX) + ", stepY: " + (215 + stepY));
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the shape move to exactly where I clicked? The problem lies with `stepX += (endX - startX) / 5;` and `stepY += (endY - startY) / 5;`. Those two lines are causing the shape not to move exactly to where I clicked, since they don't increment `stepX` and `stepY` precisely to the click and instead "round" at each increment. I don't know how to fix these two lines so that they increment `stepX` and `stepY` exactly to where I clicked and therefore stop moving the shape once it reaches `endX` and `endY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you add `215` to `stepX` and `stepY` in your `paintComponent()` method, which is why it appears to be 'way off'. This is because it draws at `stepX + 215` and `stepY + 215`, when you really want it drawn at exactly `stepX` and `stepY` (which are based on the mouse pointer at the time of clicking). Presumably the `+ 215` is just an offset for the initial location?

Simple fix is to change your `paintComponent()` method to:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillOval(stepX, stepY, 30, 30);
    startX = stepX;
    startY = stepY;
    if (stepX == endX && stepY == endY) {
        sliderTimer.stop();
    }
}
```

or just be consistent with the offset of all the coordinates.

Secondly, your `slideTimer.stop()` is highly unlikely to ever be called. You should set `stepX = endX` and `stepY = endY` if the following is true: `end - step < 5`, i.e.

```
stepX = endX - startX < 5 ? endX : stepX + (endX - startX) / 5;
stepY = endY - startY < 5 ? endY : stepY + (endY - startY) / 5;
```

This may not bring it to the nicest possible finish, so feel free to experiment.

Comment: This seems to be working fine, but you made the circle start at the corner. I want the circle to be able to start at any point, and when I click, it should move from that point to the click. I actually made this program to figure out how to make the chess pieces in the chess program I made slide to positions rather than "teleporting" to them.

Comment: @parrot15 just set the fields `startX` and `startY` to `215` initially to centre the circle again (or even better `the_panel_width / 2 - the_circle_width / 2`, e.g. `500 / 2 - 30 / 2`), or to whatever coordinates you wish.

Comment: I just deleted `startX` and `startY` because I realized I didn't need them to make the shape move. Which variable should I use to center the circle? I tried setting `stepX` and `stepY` initially to 215 but it isn't working.